# Graph is symmetrical about which line

Tags: functions

Given function:
[image]
We have to find the line for which the graph $f^{-1}(x)$ would be symmetrical.

My try:

[image]

Symmetric about origin but unable to find the line about which it symmetric

Answer (score 2):

The function is odd, and it is symmetric about no line.

---

**Update:**

Seeing the given answer, the real question is "find the line about which $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are symmetrical". It is well-known that this is

$$y=x,$$ *for any function*. There is nothing special about the given $f$.

The title is misleading.

---

**Justification:**

The vector from $(x,y)$ to $(y,x)$, i.e. $(y-x,x-y)$ is obviously orthogonal to the direction vector of $y=x$. And the midpoint, $\left(\dfrac{x+y}2,\dfrac{y+x}2\right)$ belongs to that line.

Comment: But answer is given that it is symmetrical about y=x line.

Comment: @face: see my update.

Comment: Sorry the answer is y = -x

Comment: @face: it is not. Where do you draw this from ?